# Identical Height on specific class in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this script which makes all Elememts with the class company the height of the element with the most height in px.

How can I adapt this in Internet explorer? Because it doesn't seem to work properly.

**Script:**

```
    $(window).bind("load", function () {
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('company');
        var elementHeights = Array.prototype.map.call(elements, function (el)    {
            return el.clientHeight;
        });
       var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, elementHeights);
       Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function (el) {
            el.style.height = maxHeight + "px"
        });
});
```

Comment: Does it work on other browsers properly?

Comment: Check the console to see specifically *why* it doesn't work in internet explorer. I would also suggest you update your version of jQuery as `bind()` was deprecated a long time ago.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay Yes, it works properly on Chrome, Firefox and Edge

Comment: What's the error on IE?

Comment: what the variable `maxHeight` contains?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay It contains the height of the element with the highest amount of pixels.